# How to output only d.ts of my typescript project?

Tags: typescript

For my typescript project, want to out `d.ts` file for entry file only:

when i have a **index.ts**:

```
import a from './a';
import b from './b';

export default {
   a,
   b
};
```

when i compile with ts with config **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "declarationDir": "./build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "packages/index.ts",
    "typings"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/__tests__",
    "**/__mocks__",
  ]
}
```

would output tree file **a.d.ts**, **b.d.ts**, **index.d.ts**

how only output **index.d.ts**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a separate `tsc` run with `outFile` to produce a single `.d.ts` file that has a `declare module` block for each original module.  You could do this by removing the `declaration` and `declarationDir` options from your original `tsconfig.json` and creating a separate `tsconfig.declaration.json` with:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",  // https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27117
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outFile": "build/index.d.ts"
  }
}
```

The only problem is that TypeScript 3.0.3 incorrectly passes through relative import paths such as `./a` to the output, so for now, you'll need to set up your module resolution options so that you can use non-relative import paths.  The problem has been fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26341), but the fix has not been released as of 2018-09-15.

See [this long thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433) for discussion of other approaches to declaration bundling.

Comment: Great stuff, but addition to this, you should also set `"isolatedModules": false` in the `tsconfig.declaration.json` file, See esbuild why isolatedModules:true may be useful: https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#isolated-modules